# Handle counters with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, transactions, atomic

I have always been using **transactional databases**, which make things like this quite easy:

Table `City` contains a column named `populationCount` which is updated every time a `Person` with that `city_id` is added/deleted.

How to do it with a **non-transactional database like MongoDB**? Suppose that the collection `Person` contains millions of documents: should I always query the population count or is there an easy way to store `populationCount` in `City`? I have seen a [transaction example on the MongoDB website](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/), but it talks about the classic example of transferring money from A to B. I hope that my problem is much easier.

Comment: Does that population count of a city have to be 100% accurate?

Comment: That would be nice. Otherwise I woud just use `$inc` on the `City` document.

Comment: A 'nice to have' is not the same as a 'must have'.

Comment: That's true. I don't even have to collect any population of any city, I just want to learn and I made up a possible situation. *Nice* stands for *I want to find the solution for the most difficult situation, but you are free to tell me other ways that may accomplish the same thing*.

Comment: Okay, so there is no screaming manager standing behind you :)

Comment: @GuidoLodetti: What i m  understanding person is a collection in which contains document regarding each person detail and also u r adding and removing documents from person collection. so,that means total number of document in person collection is total population so, you can calculate population by db.collection.count()

Answer (score 1):

Is is a problem when the population count of the city is one less then the real population count of that city in collection Persons?

If yes then you can use a ReaderWriterLock in your application. That means that only one thread can do writing simultaneously, you write a document to the persons collection and you increase the population count in collection city and there will be no reading when there is writing going on but when there is no writing happening all the threads that want to read can read simultaneously.